# Сделать проверку на отправку сообщений discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Мне нужно сделать проверку сообщений в канале и чтобы бот на них ставил реакции. 
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
async def on_message(ctx):
  if ctx.channel.id == 1008150308398059601:
    reactions = ["✅", "❌", "➖"]
    for i in reactions:
      await ctx.add_reaction(i)
```

Comment: если это дополнение к вопросу, то туда это и запишите, пожалуйста.